# How do I get a key-value pair out of a JSON string using jq

Tags: json, string, object, jq

This is what I have:

```
{
    "ARN": "sdfsdfsdfsdfds",
    "Name": "sdfsdfsdfsdsf",
    "VersionId": "sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf",
    "SecretString": "{\"username\":\"myusername\",\"password\":\"mypassword\"}",
    "VersionStages": [
        "AWSCURRENT"
    ],
    "CreatedDate": 1541641750.607
}
```

How do I get `mykey` and `myvalue` out of this JSON?

`jq '.SecretString' -r` gives me this:

```
{"username":"myusername","password":"mypassword"}
```

But how do I get `myusername` and `mypassword` out of that?

Ok, this seems to work, but should I be piping it back into jq like this? Feels like im doing it wrong:

```
jq '.SecretString' -r | jq '.username' -r
jq '.SecretString' -r | jq '.password' -r
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.SecretString` is not so secret, but it is the JSON string representation of a JSON object. To parse it, simply use `fromjson`, so you could, for example, obtain the username with:

```
.SecretString | fromjson | .username
```